# How to create a condition to check if the datatable item is null in vb

Tags: vb.net, dbnull

Now I want if the `dt.rows(i).item(0)` is null, then some code..

This is my code:

```
If dtpay.Rows(i).Item(23).ToString Is Nothing Then
  GoTo finalline
End If
```

But seems like the code is not working..
Thanks a lot for your concern :D

Comment: @JaydipJ that's ok in VB.Net. You might be thinking of C#

Comment: @lan Yes I think that library function are used by C# and VB are same. Thanks for Info

Comment: A note: you have some `vb6` in your code specifically the `goto`. Also `dtpay.Rows(i).Item(23) Is DBNull.Value` will work to see if it's null...

Comment: Thank you for your intention to help :D

Answer (score 3):

You can use `GetType()` to check if an object is `DBNull` in `VB.Net`:

```
If dtpay.Rows(i).Item(23).GetType() Is GetType(DBNull) Then
    'Do something
End If
```

That being said, the `DBNull` in your code above may also happen in the `dtpay.Rows(i)`. Thus, check also where the `DBNull` occurs.

Comment: This code still not working... Actually i want to skip all the code below when the item(23) is null.. Do you have any way other than this solution? Im sorry and thank you for you help

Comment: In what sense does it not working? Does it go to the `If` block?

Comment: I run this on try block.. Anyway i dont set the GoTo  to outside of try block

Comment: The first thing you may need to check is if it is actually entering the `If` block - not the `try` block. Because it shouldn't go out of the `try` block if there is no `exception`

Comment: @JohnsYong does any of the answer help you? If it does, please do not forget to accept (tick V in the top left of the answer) and/or upvote it (press up-arrow in the top left of the answer). You could accept only *one* answer, but you could *upvote* as many answers as you want.

Comment: The answers from Ian, Veeke, and Tim Schmelter all work.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`DataRow.IsNull`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.isnull(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
If dtpay.Rows(i).IsNull(23) Then
  ' ..... '
End If
```

If it's a value type(like `Integer`) you can also use the `DataRow`-extension method [`Field`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.field(v=vs.90).aspx):

```
Dim myNullableField As Int32? = dtpay.Rows(i).Field(Of Int32?)
If Not myNullableField.HasValue Then
  ' you get it's value via myNullableField.Value '
End If
```

Comment: This code also still not working... Actually i want to skip all the code below when the item(23) is null.. Do you have any way other than this solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: @JohnsYong: your code does the opposite, if it is `DnBull` you will enter the code. If you don't want that: `If Not dtpay.Rows(i).IsNull(23) Then`

Comment: I just got the solution. Thank you for your help.. I dont know why but this code is working. Anyway, thank you very much for your help! Im using this kind of code:

If dt.Rows(i).Item(23) Is Nothing OrElse dt.Rows(i).Item(23).ToString = "" OrElse dt.Rows(i).Item(23) = vbNull Then
GoTo finalline
End If

Comment: The answers from Ian, Veeke, and Tim Schmelter all work.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is not the same as Null.
Nothing returns the default value for the type of the field (0 for numbers, "" for text,...)

```
    If IsDBNull(dtpay.Rows(i).Item(23)) Then
        GoTo finalline
    End If
```

Comment: Im sorry but this code also seems like not working.. Do you have any other solution? Thanks a lot helper :D

Comment: The answers from Ian, Veeke, and Tim Schmelter all work.

Answer (score 0):

Try just :

```
If dtpay.Rows(i).Item(23) Is Nothing Then
  GoTo finalline
End If
```

Comment: if you want to skip all the code below when the item(23) is null : try this line  If dtpay.Rows(i).Item(23) Is Nothing Then exit sub  Or  If IsDBNull((dtpay.Rows(i).Item(23)) Then exit sub

Answer (score 0):

If dt.Rows(i).Item(23) Is Nothing OrElse dt.Rows(i).Item(23).ToString = "" OrElse dt.Rows(i).Item(23) = vbNull Then
GoTo finalline
End If